# UITableViewCell highlight covers my accessoryView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a checkbox, when its checked, it gets checkmarked. But when i select the cell, the highlight covers up the checkbox. Sorry for my horrible english, but here is the code below. Is there a way for me to have the checkmark button on top of the highlight?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

if([tableView isEqual:self.myTableView]){
    static NSString *TableViewIdentifier = @"MyCells";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableViewIdentifier];
    } 
    //configure the cell
    checkbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect checkboxRect = CGRectMake(135, 150, 36, 36);
    [checkbox setFrame:checkboxRect];  
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = checkbox;


    NSString *group;
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            group = [suggestedPeople objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 1:
            group = [aArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 2:
            group = [bArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 3:
            group = [cArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 4:
            group = [dArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 5:
            group = [eArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 6:
            group = [fArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 7:
            group = [gArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 8:
            group = [hArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 9:
            group = [iArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 10:
            group = [jArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 11:
            group = [kArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;
        case 12:
            group = [lArray objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.textLabel.text = group;
            break;

    }
}
return cell;}
```

and some of my other methods:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"cell is touched");
if(checkbox.state == UIControlStateNormal){
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}else if (checkbox.state == UIControlStateSelected) {
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}}

-(void)checkboxClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
sender.selected = !sender.selected;

UITableViewCell *ownerCell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
NSIndexPath *ownerCellIndexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:ownerCell];

if(sender.selected){

}else{

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the place of :

```
[checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Use

```
 [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Might Help